# Populate Object using Ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

As the title says, I'm trying to populate the properties of an object using jQuery-Ajax. I've been trying to find the right way to do it for hours, but couldn't make it work...

This is my code:

```
function Persona(){
    this.nombre;
    this.apellido;
    this.buscarNombre= function(callback){
    $.get("nombre.php", function(datos){
        datos = eval("(" + datos + ")");
        this.nombre = datos.nombre;
        this.apellido = datos.apellido;
        alert(this.nombre);
      })
    };
}

$(document).ready(function(){
       var pp = new Persona();
       alert(pp.nombre);

}
```

I think the problem is the scope of the function that retrieves the data from the server it's different from the scope of the object, but I don't realize how to pass the data from one place to the other...

The data is arriving perfectly from the web server... I used FireBug to be sure...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need to call the actual function? `pp.buscarNombre();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you replace `alert(pp.nombre);` with `pp.buscarNombre();`. You will get the desired results. And your this reference is wrong:

```
function Persona(){
    var self = this;    
    this.nombre;
    this.apellido;

    this.buscarNombre= function(callback){
        $.get("nombre.php", function(datos){
            datos = eval("(" + datos + ")");
            self.nombre = datos.nombre;
            self.apellido = datos.apellido;
            alert(self.nombre);
        })
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
       var pp = new Persona();
       pp.buscarNombre();    
}
```